# Arduino digitalRead() always returns LOW

Tags: c, embedded, arduino

I am using a bread boarded arduino. Inside my interrupt functions I want to read the value of one of my GPIO pins and then increment a counter if it is low. I am doing that using the following.

```
displayValues[4]++;
hasButtonPushed = true;

if(digitalRead(BUTTON_A) == LOW) {
    displayValues[5]++;
}
if(digitalRead(BUTTON_B) == LOW) {
    displayValues[6]++;
}
if(digitalRead(BUTTON_C) == LOW) {
    displayValues[7]++;
}
```

However, even when the input line is directly tied to high, the code returns low. I don't believe that my Atmel is damaged. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you declared the buttons as inputs?

Comment: This might actually be a question for the EE stack exchange - my guess is that it has to do more with how your pins are connected to ground than anything. Electricity, like water, follows the path of least resistance, and if it can go through any of the other buttons or any other connection to reach ground instead of the Atmel (where it would provide the 2.5+v or whatever the threshold is), it will. You need to make sure that the Atmel is the path of least resistance or the voltage won't reach the high state.

Comment: I will try posting there that thanks and yes the pins have been declared as inputs. My mutimeter reads them as high but the atmel doesnt.

Comment: @secretformula have you tried testing this in a simple main loop() example rather than in an interupt handler? The handler does some odd things to the timing etc

Comment: Yes I did, It didn't work, I am going to try rewriting in pure AVR code. I am beginning to think my compiler may be doing something wrong as this code didnt work on a different chip.

Comment: What is LOW declared as? Have you tried modifying the blinky program to light the LED when the button is pressed?

Comment: LOW is 0. I ended up fixing the problem by rewriting digital inputs in native AVR and everything is solved. There must be a problem with their code library

Comment: @secretformula Wouldn't mind seeing the finished code. Also you should add it and accept it as your answer for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an issue with the arduino library that was causing digital read not to work. The newer arduino versions fixed this issue but I got around it by rewriting everything into native AVR.

Comment: What version of Arduino library was it that was causing digital read not to work?

Comment: It was a version prior to 1, im not sure exactly.